# Pass parameter to the new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, lotus-notes

I was looking for the answer to this problem and found the solution, which I used in my programm. However, I still can not work with the parameter. I am programming an agent in Java for Lotus Notes and I need to pass Notes object called "Session" to my GUI:

This is my thread class:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    Session par;

    public MyRunnable(final Session parameter) {
        this.par = parameter;
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

This is my agent class:

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {
        try {
            final Session s = getSession();
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new MyRunnable(s){
                public void run() {
                    RemoveFromDenyGUI re = new RemoveFromDenyGUI(this.par);
                    re.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I want to use session in the `RemoveFromDenyGUI` class, it says object was removed or recycled.

Comment: I presume `Session` is a _session_. What you have is a [clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) - this means that the lifecycle of the `Session` exceeds the initial scope. I think you need to pass in a factory object of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a multi-threaded application using the Lotus Notes Java API, you should read tnhis  [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESTHREAD_CLASS_JAVA.html) and this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/).

The simplest solution is to have your class extend NotesThread in order to inherit the initialization that is required for threads in the API.  If that's not how you want to do it, then check out the sample code in the second link, specifically the example in the section labeled "Execute threads through the Runnable interface" (reproduced below just in case it ever goes away), paying special attention to the use of the NotesThread and NotesFactory classes.

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class myClass implements Runnable

{
    public static void main(String argv[])    
    {    
        myClass t = new myClass();        
        NotesThread nt = new NotesThread((Runnable)t);        
        nt.start();        
        }        
            public void run() // entry point for thread
        {        
            try            
            {            
                Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();                
                // Operational code goes here
                }            
                catch (Exception e)            
                {            
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code from a *Language* perspective.  When it calls `new RemoveFromDenyGUI(this.par)` the `this.par` arg will reference the same Session object that was returned by the `getSession()` call.

But what is `Session`?  lotus.domino.Session?  That's something I can only guess about.  I can't give you a real answer but maybe I can start you looking in the right direction.

You say, "When I want to use session in the RemoveFromDenyGUI class, it says object was removed or recycled."

Assuming that's a bad thing, then apparently the Session object is either no longer valid (closed?) by the time it is used in the Event Dispatch Thread, or else it is only valid in the thread that obtained it.